# Powershell - Write-Host printing in wrong place

Tags: powershell

My code has the following function:

```
function status{
    if ($args[0] -eq "Stopped"){
        Write-Host -NoNewline "Stopped" -fore red
    .....
    }
}
```

and the function is used as:

```
...
Write-Host "$($count)) $($i.DisplayName)   STATUS: $(status $i.State)"
...
```

The result after script execution is:

> **Stopped** 1) XXXXXX                   STATUS:

Why "Stopped" is in the beginning of the line? can someone help me?
The function is only to change the text color. As the example `-fore red` is to Stopped value.

Comment: After STATUS ie: STATUS: Stopped

Comment: In your function, return the string rather than calling Write-Host.

Comment: Return works fine as you said, but I'd like to change the text color. I only know -fore and it don't work with return. Is there some workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [ANSI Escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) for this but it wouldn't work in old terminals. I'm not convinced if this is possible combining outputs from [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-7.2) and, if it is, I'll assume is an extremely tedious task.

```bash
function status {
    $ansi = switch($args[0]) {
        Stopped { "$([char] 27)[91m" }
        Running { "$([char] 27)[32m" }
    }
    $ansi + $args[0]
}

foreach($state in 'Running', 'Stopped') {
    $count++
    $i = [pscustomobject]@{ state = $state; displayname = 'Hello!' }
    Write-Host "$($count)) $($i.DisplayName)   STATUS: $(status $i.State)"
}
```

Which would produce the following output:

[image: example]

Answer (score 2):

**[Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72988480/45375) provides an effective solution**; let me complement it with an explanation of **what you tried**:

> Why "Stopped" is in the beginning of the line?

The reason is that [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) doesn't write to PowerShell's *success* [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) and therefore doesn't "return" a value from your `status` function.

Instead, `Write-Host` *instantly* prints to the *host* (display; in PSv5+ via the *information* stream), *before* exiting the function, and your function produces no success-stream output.

Since subexpressions (via [`$(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--)) are evaluated *first* in an expandable string (or command in general):

- the `Write-Host` call inside your `status` function executes right away and prints at the *start* of the line.
- only then does the outer `Write-Host` call execute, which - due to the inner call's `-NoNewLine` switch - prints on the same line, *after* what the function printed, and `$(status $i.State)`, due to the `status` call producing no success output, evaluates to the *empty string*.

A simple example can illustrate the problem:

```bash
Write-Host "foo: >>$(Write-Host bar)<<"
```

Output:

```bash
bar         # The inner Write-Host printed right away.
foo >><<    # $(Write-Host bar) produced no success output
```

---

Santiago's solution avoids this problem by replacing the `Write-Host` call inside the function with sending a string (implicitly) *to the success output stream*, so that it becomes the function's "return value" that subexpression `$(status $i.State)` expands to, and to make this string *colored*, ANSI / VT escape sequences are needed.

Note that while `"$([char] 27)"` is required in *Windows PowerShell* to embed an ESC character in an expanable string, *PowerShell (Core) 7+* now offers escape sequence `` "`e" ``

Also, *PowerShell (Core) 7.2+* offers the [automatic `$PSStyle` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psstyle), which, while more verbose, offers a more descriptive way to embed ANSI / VT escape sequences; e.g.:

```bash
# Prints only the word "green" in green.
"It ain't easy being $($PSStyle.Foreground.Green)green$($PSStyle.Reset)."
```

Note:

- If you send strings with ANSI / VT sequences to the success output stream, as in the example above, colors are *not* automatically reset; `$PSStyle.Reset` is needed for a manual reset.
- By contrast, if `Write-Host` prints a string, it resets colors *automatically*.