# Powershell Different color in strings with echo in array

Tags: powershell

I trying to write a script, which show iis pools state with a different color.
And I can't understand why script coloring in one color all strings when I use echo.
Here script:

```
    $pools = invoke-command -session $session -scriptblock {Import-Module WebAdministration; Get-ChildItem IIS:\AppPools | Where {$_.Name -like "*abc*"}}
    $poolsShow = $pools | Select-Object -Property name, state
    $poolsShow | ForEach-Object {
        if($_.state -eq "Started") { 
            $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = "Green";
            echo $_;
            [Console]::ResetColor();
        }
        if($_.state -eq "Stopped") { 
            $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = "Red";
            echo $_;
            [Console]::ResetColor();
        }
    }
```

It is work if I go through the $pools, but if I select name and state via Select-Object - all strings are coloring in the color of the last service.
I have tried via Write-Host - and it's worked, but I didn't find a way, how to format output in one table with a headers only at first line and with the same width in every string.

Comment: You could update the objects property values prepending ANSI escaping sequences like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72988311/powershell-write-host-printing-in-wrong-place/72988480#72988480

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a similar approach as the one proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72988480/15339544), the only difference would be that the [ANSI Escape Sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) are prepended to the property values of the objects created by [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2). Helpful answer provided by [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72988710/15339544) in the same question provides more details on this.

```
function status {
    $ansi = switch($args[0]) {
        Stopped { "$([char] 27)[91m" }
        Started { "$([char] 27)[32m" }
    }
    $ansi + $args[0]
}

Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    Import-Module WebAdministration
    Get-ChildItem IIS:\AppPools | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*abc*" }
} | Select-Object Name, @{ N='Status'; E={ status $_.State }}
```

A demo using custom objects:

```
0..5 | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name   = "Test $_"
        Status = ('Started', 'Stopped')[$_ % 2]
    }
} | Select-Object Name, @{ N='Status'; E={ status $_.Status }}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: @zett42 PSStyle is not available in Windows PowerShell

Comment: As an aside, if you have PowerShell 7+ available, you can avoid hardcoded ANSI escape sequences by using the `$PSStyle` variable: `Stopped { $PSStyle.Formatting.Error } Started { $PSStyle.Foreground.BrightGreen }`

Comment: I'm surprised this works actually, since there is no ANSI reset code, AFAICT.

Comment: @not2qubit sure there is, the reset code is `"$([char] 27)[0m"` but there is no need here because these are property values not a simple string. see in my profile I have a regex example using the reset code for a rainbow string

Answer (score 2):

To complement [Santiago's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73558896/45375):

As for **what you tried**:

- `echo` in PowerShell is a built-in alias for [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output), which does *not* print directly to the console - instead, it prints to the [*success output stream*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams).
- If the success output stream isn't captured or redirected in a given command, it is eventually printed to the console, after undergoing for-display formatting by PowerShell's [formatting system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/format/formatting-file-overview).
- Because your output objects have 4 or fewer properties, PowerShell applies *tabular* formatting by default; that is, the [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table) cmdlet is *implicitly* used, which has a perhaps surprising implication:

  - So as to allow determining suitable column widths for the table, a 300-millisecond *delay* is introduced during which the objects are internally cached and analyzed.
  - While this behavior is helpful in principle, it has surprising side effects, notably in that direct-to-host output and output from other streams then can appear *out of order*; a simple example: `[pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1 }; Write-Host 'Why am I printing first??` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43691123/45375) for background information.
- Therefore, the formatted table's rows only started printing *after* that delay, so your attempt to control their color *one by one* with `ForEach-Object` was ineffective.

  - As an aside: In *PowerShell (Core) 7.2+* there's an additional consideration: formatted output now applies its own coloring by default, as controlled by the `.OutputRendering` property of the [`$PSStyle` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#psstyle).
- Santiago's answer bypasses this problem by using a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) to color *individual property values* rather than trying to control the coloring of the already-formatted representation of the object.

---

If you want a ***prepackaged*, general-purpose solution**, you can use the **`Out-HostColored` function** from [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/243ea8297e7db0e1c03a67ce4b1e765d) (authored by me), which in your case would make the solution as simple as piping your objects to 
`Out-HostColored.ps1 @{ Started = 'Green'; Stopped = 'Red' }`:

````
# Download and define function `Out-HostColored` on demand (will prompt).
# To be safe, inspect the source code at the specified URL first.
if (-not (Get-Command -ErrorAction Ignore Out-HostColored1)) {
  $gistUrl = 'https://gist.github.com/mklement0/243ea8297e7db0e1c03a67ce4b1e765d/raw/Out-HostColored.ps1'
  if ((Read-Host "`n====`n  OK to download and define function ``Out-HostColored```n  from Gist ${gistUrl}?`n=====`n(y/n)?").Trim() -notin 'y', 'yes') { Write-Warning 'Aborted.'; exit 2 }
  Invoke-RestMethod $gistUrl | Invoke-Expression 3>$null
  if (-not ${function:Out-HostColored}) { exit 2 }
}

# Emit sample objects and color parts of their formatted representation
# based on regex patterns.
0..5 | ForEach-Object {
  [pscustomobject]@{
    Name  = "Test $_"
    State = ('Started', 'Stopped')[$_ % 2]
  }
} | 
  Out-HostColored.ps1 @{ Started = 'Green'; Stopped = 'Red' }
````

Output:

[image: screenshot]

<sup>Add `-WholeLine` if you want to color matching lines *in full*.</sup>

- The hashtable maps search text patterns to colors.
- Whenever a pattern is found in the formatted representations of the input objects, it is colored using the specified color.

  - Note that this means that finding what to color is purely based on *string parsing*, not on OOP features (such as checking specific properties).
- Note that the hashtable keys are [regexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) by default, unless you also specify
  `-SimpleMatch`.

  - Thus you could easily make the above more robust, if needed, such as replacing `Started =` with `'\bStarted\b' =`  in order to only match full words.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about delay! It was unclear for me why coloring didn't work for every line, when I used foreach. But why this work for array if I don't use Select-Object -Property name, state?($pools in my example) Why we don't have delay here?

Comment: @IlyaAfinogentov, there are two likely explanations: without `Select-Object`, (a) perhaps you're getting a _list_ representation (implicit `Format-List`), which is _not_ subject to the delay or (b) the output objects are of a type that has _predefined formatting data_ associated with it, which is also not subject to the delay, because the column widths are predefined.

Comment: Yes, it has list representation. Thanks a lot! It's clear now.