# How to highlight the properties of Select-String results with different colors?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to mimic `grep` using powershell, and would like to improve the readability of output of the `Select-String`, by giving different colors to the different properties.

```
# Select-String -Path <sometext-file> -AllMatches -Pattern <regEx>
function nix_grep {
    if( $args.count -eq 0) { 
        Write-Host -f Red "Error: " -Non; Write-Host "Please provide a RegEx argument to grep." 
        Write-Host -f DarkYellow "Usage: grep <file/path> <RegEx>" 
    } else {
        if ($args.count -eq 2) { Select-String -Path $args[0] -AllMatches -Pattern $args[1] }
    } 
}

Set-Alias -Name grep -Value nix_grep 


grep ".\zx_ASCII.txt" "ABCD"
# zx_ASCII.txt:1:1234 5678 ABCD EFGH
# zx_ASCII.txt:7:!"#$%&'()*+,-./0ABCD


grep ".\zx_ASCII.txt" "ABCD" | select Filename, LineNumber, pattern, Line

# Filename     LineNumber Pattern Line
# --------     ---------- ------- ----
# zx_ASCII.txt          1 ABCD    1234 5678 ABCD EFGH
# zx_ASCII.txt          7 ABCD    !"#$%&'()*+,-./0ABCD
```

Q: **How can I output these with different colors?**
(..and still have the matched pattern inverted.)

Comment: inject ansi escape sequences as shown here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73558896/15339544

Comment: Is the question about how `Select-String` highlights the matched pattern ? If so, you can use the `MatchInfo.ToEmphasizedString` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a tricky exercise, but the result was worthwhile and now providing a very good looking `grep` result.

```
function ansi-reverse {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position=0)] [string] $txt,   # raw text string
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position=1)] [string] $pat    # Pattern string
    )
    
    $ESC = "$([char] 27)"   # ANSI ESC (0x1b)
    $RES = "`e[0m"          # ANSI Reset ()
    $RON = "`e[7m"          # Reverse
    $ROF = "`e[27m"         # ReverseOff
    $RED = "`e[91m"         # BrightRed
    $GRY = "`e[90m"         # BrightBlack / "DarkGray"

    # Replace text pattern with ANSI Reversed version (and using capture group for case preserve)
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/1147688
    $txt = "$txt" -replace "($pat)", "$RED`$1$GRY"      # Using: BrightRed

    Return "$txt"
}

function print-color {
    param( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position=0)] [string] $i,     # Filename
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position=1)] [string] $j,     # Linenumber
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position=2)] [string] $k,     # Line
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position=3)] [string] $p      # Pattern
    )
    
    $fn = " {0}  " -f $i
    $nn = ": {0,-5}: " -f $j
    $ln = (ansi-reverse "$k" "$p")
    
    Write-Host -f DarkYellow "$fn" -non
    Write-Host -f Yellow "$nn" -non
    Write-Host -f DarkGray "$ln"
}

function nix_grep {
    if( $args.count -eq 0) { 
        Write-Host -f Red "Error: " -Non; Write-Host "Please provide a RegEx argument to grep." 
        Write-Host -f DarkYellow "Usage: grep <file/path> <RegEx>"  
    } else {
        if ($args.count -eq 2) { 
            $A = Select-String -Path $args[0] -AllMatches -Pattern $args[1] 
            $A | select Filename, LineNumber, Pattern, Line | %{ 
                $i = $_.Filename
                $j = $_.Linenumber
                $k = $_.Line
                $p = $_.Pattern
                print-color "$i" "$j" "$k" "$p"
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

The output becomes:

[image]

---

Extra Credit:

- It would be great to be able to pipe text into this grep...

Comment: "*It would be great to be able to pipe text into this grep...*" You might want create a proxy command for this, see: [Proxy Functions: Spice Up Your PowerShell Core Cmdlets](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/proxy-functions-spice-up-your-powershell-core-cmdlets/)

Comment: @iRon Very cool. Thank you for sharing. However, that blog is not easy to read and it's code highlighting is terrible. But I think you suggest to wrap the command into something that would create the equivalent of a temp file, and then pass that to the command as above? My first tack at implementing a pipe, didn't work as I wasn't formatting the `param()`'s which messed up the rest.

Comment: I have placed a step by step **How to wrap a PowerShell command** in this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77635452/1701026

Comment: I forgot to mention that *mklement0* has a very nice similar colorizing function [`Out-HostColored`](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/243ea8297e7db0e1c03a67ce4b1e765d).  In fact I could have used it, but decided not to, as his function is far more complicated.  He also has another gist for color/ highlight grepping using RegEx.

Comment: An important difference with (the wrapped) `Select-String` cmdlet and your function (and the `Out-HostColored` from *mklement0*) is that (the wrapped) `Select-String` writes to [Success Stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams) instead of the `Information Stream`.